# Wire _KeyDown event of textbox to a _click event of button control

Tags: c#, events, controls, event-handling

I have a form with a textbox called 'tbWO.'  This field is used to enter a Purchase Order Number.  I also have a button control called 'btnFill.'  When btnFill is clicked, it fills a dataset with a parameter from 'tbWO.'

I would like to be able to press 'ENTER' in the 'tbWO' textbox (after a Purchase Order # is entered) and have it fire the btnFill_Click event I mentioned above.

I tried with this bit of errant, badly written code - but, it's just not working properly, i.e., at all, or how I think it should work.  Anyway, the code is below; in all it's glory.

```
        private void txtWO_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            btnFill.Click += new EventHandler(btnFill_Click);
        }
    }
```

I will admit confusion on using 'new EvenHandler( ?? ).  Fairly new to C# (as is probably blantantly obvious.)

Any help, links, suggestions - all are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Jasoomian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this...

```
private void txtWO_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)    {        
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)        {            
         btnFill_Click();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Change btnFill_Click() to

btnFill_Click(sender, e);

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, I abhor mapping one event handler to another. Instead, write a separate function, and have both event handlers invoke that separate function. Something like this:

```
private void txtWO_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        AcceptInput();
    }
}

private void btnFill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AcceptInput();
}

private void AcceptInput()
{
    // Do clever stuff here when the user presses enter 
    // in the field, or clicks the button.
}
```

Granted, you may feel differently, but it accomplishes the same thing, but with (IMO) far more readable code. But it's been my experience that criss-crossing event handlers is *very* sloppy and leads to maintenance headaches out the wazoo.

Comment: Nice approach to the issue, Mike.  I hadn't thought about the impact of crossing the event handlers. Thanks again.